# how to change host in django-robots?

Tags: python, django, robots.txt

I am struggling to add robots.txt I am using this library Django-robots and I have everything set as well, I am stuck on the hostname at sitemap showing example.com the documentation link https://django-robots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWUPu.png

'''

```
#sitemaps.py

class StaticViewsSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
priority  = 1.0
changefreq = "daily"

def items(self):
    return [
    'home',
]
def location(self, items):
    return reverse(items)

class SnippetSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):

priority  = 1.0
changefreq = "daily"

def items(self):
    return Snippet.objects.all()

#urls.py 
urlpatterns = [
...
path('<slug:slug>/', views.Snippet_detail),    
url(r'^robots1\.txt', include('robots.urls')),
url(r'^sitemap1.xml$', cache_page(60*60*1)(sitemap),
{'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='cached-sitemap'),
...
]

#models.py

class Snippet(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
body = models.TextField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return f'/{self.slug}/'
```

'''

Comment: Did you set the domain name for your site? See the docs for [Enabling the sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework).

Comment: I tried this in the documentation but nothing change

Comment: Did you set the domain name for the `Site` instance? You can do that from the admin site or by using a data migration as the documentation states.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful